# lz4 includes not found

Tags: ros, rosdep, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building on Mac Sierra, I got an error, and then used this command to reproduce. By the way, excellent logging and tools for trying to narrow down the problem! Anyway, here's the command:

```
cd /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roslz4 && /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_comm/roslz4 -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslz4 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

This command gives the following error in trying to build roslz4 and I can't find any info on where to look to fix it.

```
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/roslz4
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roslz4/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/local/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
  lz4 includes not found


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roslz4/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267094/lz4-includes-not-found/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is part of the many problems in getting ROS up on Mac. You can read my summary of this experience in another question. Bottom line, I abandoned trying to install it on Mac, there are just too many loose ends. I am having far better success with running ROS under VMWare with Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) with karma: 628 on 2017-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On Debian 9 I fixed the same issue installing **liblz4-dev**

---

Originally posted by [giuspen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33420/giuspen/) with karma: 21 on 2018-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
That should not be necessary (`rosdep` has rules for `lz4`: [here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/14eed310c8d27961ed7e66fb1391357fb42a4577/rosdep/base.yaml#L3433)). If something is not working, it might be worth to report it as an issue.

**Comment by [giuspen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33420/giuspen/) on 2018-01-25**:
I think it doesn't work on Debian 9 where I installed python-rosdep but still had many missing dependencies  later when building kinetic (or this package has just an outdated dependency list)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
`python-rosdep` does not pull in those dependencies (such as `lz4`). You'd have to invoke `rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src ...` for that.

**Comment by [giuspen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33420/giuspen/) on 2018-01-25**:
I'm aware of rosdep install --from-paths WORKSPACE --ignore-src --rosdistro=ROSDISTRO but in my case I'm installing the whole system, I have no sources yet

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
Are you doing a source install, or using regular `deb`s?

**Comment by [giuspen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33420/giuspen/) on 2018-01-25**:
I'm doing a source install, didn't find existing debs for Debian 9

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-25**:
If you're doing a source install than you *must* have run `rosdep install`. It's one of the required steps. That should've installed the right `lz4` packages for you.

If it didn't, that would be a problem and should be reported.

**Comment by [giuspen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33420/giuspen/) on 2018-01-25**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn I definitely missed that